# MatchError after sorting a Set

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

This code compiles fine, but fails at runtime:

```
    val values = Set("a").toSeq.sorted
    values match {
      case Nil => println("empty")
      case h::t => println(s"h = $h")
    }
```

With the error message:

> scala.MatchError: ArrayBuffer(a) (of class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer)

I understand that somewhere in the process an `ArrayBuffer` is created, on which I cannot pattern-match like this. However, why can't the compiler tell me that this is not going to work?

Comment: Because `::` is just a function (`unapply`) and the compiler cannot know what it will and won't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching on an open (extensible) data type, Scala's `Seq`. It could be a `List`, so Scala doesn't complain with your List pattern. On the other hand, exhaustiveness cannot be checked because it could really be any class implementing `Seq` (that we may not even know statically), so Scala just trusts you on this one.

You can use generic `Seq` patterns instead:

```
values match {
  case Seq() => println("empty")
  case h +: t => println(s"h = $h")
}
```

Or just convert to a `List` and use the same patterns (but `List`s are not very efficient data structures, so it's probably better with the first option).

```
val values = Set("a").toList.sorted
values match {
  case Nil => println("empty")
  case h::t => println(s"h = $h")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting errors from pattern matching can be tricky sometimes, but in this case:

```
scala> :type values
Seq[String]

scala> Seq(1,2,3) match { case h::t => "ok" }
res1: String = ok
```

There's not enough type info to say it can't work, and it errs on the side of not annoying you.